# Multiplying euclidean vector with ket vector

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, vectors

The commutator of position operator $\mathbf x$ with the translation operator defined as $\mathscr{J}\left(d \mathbf{x}^{\prime}\right)\left|\mathbf{x}^{\prime}\right\rangle=\left|\mathbf{x}^{\prime}+d \mathbf{x}^{\prime}\right\rangle$ is  $\mathbf {dx'}$ where sakurai says "$\mathbf {dx'}$ is a number multiplied by a identity operator"

So:
$[\mathbf x, \mathscr{J( d\mathbf x'}]= d\mathbf x' \mathbf 1 $

Then
$[\mathbf x, \mathscr{J( \mathbf dx'}] |u \rangle
    = \mathbf{dx'}\mathbf 1|u \rangle =\mathbf {dx'}$  $| u\rangle$

Isn't this number $\mathbf {dx'}$ actually a euclidean vector? And we are multiplying a euclidean vector with a ket vector, which I've not seen how that's defined.

What does $\mathbf {dx'}$  $|u\rangle$ mean then?

Comment: There are some problems with your latex, what do you want to indicate with these dots? Also you switch between primed and unprimed and bold and non bold d and x a lot, is that on purpose?

Comment: This chapter of Sakurai is why I started hating QM at some point, he is saying $\mathbf{x}^{\prime}+d \mathbf{x}^{\prime}$ is an eigenvalue,  what this means is that he is using a product space of the eigen spaces of the x, y and z position operators , this means $\hat x_i |\mathbf{x}\rangle =x_i |\mathbf{x}\rangle $, but what an eigenvalue that is itself a vector would be, i really don't know. And in the chapter Sakurai himself refers to (1.4 ) he also defines it like above, for each operator separately, what this vector eigenvalue business is I don't know. I just really hate this book.

Comment: Maybe [this answer helps](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/581432/71413) but I think it's just a really horrible book to learn from... a vector can't be an eigenvalue, maybe in some fancy notation, but not at this stage in a beginner book and not without comment.

Comment: The point is that one must say what $|\mathbf{x}\rangle$ means. In general, it should mean something like $|x\rangle \otimes |y\rangle \otimes |z\rangle$. The $X$ operator on this new Hilbert space (the three-fold tensor product of 1D spaces) is then lifted to $X\otimes \mathbb I \otimes \mathbb I$ and similarly for $Y$ and $Z$.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker I am not confident enough with this math  to write an answer but I think this is what kashmirs confusion stems from, as did mine long ago. So maybe that would really help. Sakurai is so "student friendly" that tensor products are never brought up...

Comment: @Kuhlambo,edited  it to remove those dots

Comment: You can multiply any ket vector with any complex number so something like $a |u\rangle$ makes perfect sense. What is it that bothers you if I write $\vec{a} | u \rangle = ( a_1 | u \rangle , a_2 | u \rangle , a_3 | u \rangle )$?

Comment: @Kuhlambo, from which book did you study QM then? I would like to know because I'm self studying. Thank you

Comment: @Prahar, please see the answer below.

Comment: I find Shankar pretty good at least in some respects he has the only good explanation of what a function as an element of an infinite dimensional vector space is, that is suitable for the mathematically under educated (like me), and Ballentine in others (explains what bras really are for example which is nothing mysterious, just more math and not what Sakurai says which is "some kind of mirror image"...) but many love Sakurai so, who am I to naysay him...

Comment: @Kuhlambo, did you check out Cohen Tannoudji?

Comment: Did not like it at the time, but I knew even less of the necessary math so I am not sure that opinion is well founded, it's very long and detailed which can be bad if you're using it for a lecture but may be really good on your own, so who knows. ^^

Answer (score 2):

The expression
$$[\hat{\mathbf x}, \mathscr T(\mathrm d\mathbf x)] = \mathrm d\mathbf x\  \mathbb I$$
is shorthand for the three equations
$$[\hat x,\mathscr T(\mathrm d\mathbf x) ] = \mathrm dx \ \mathbb I\qquad 
[\hat y,\mathscr T(\mathrm d\mathbf x)] = \mathrm dy\ \mathbb I\qquad 
[\hat z,\mathscr T(\mathrm d\mathbf x)] = \mathrm dz \ \mathbb I$$

or, in index form, $[\hat x_i ,\mathscr T(\mathrm d\mathbf x)] = \mathrm dx_i$.  This can be proven straightforwardly:

$$[\hat x_i ,\mathscr T(\mathrm d\mathbf x)] |\mathbf x\rangle = \hat x_i \mathscr T(\mathrm d\mathbf x)|\mathbf x\rangle - \mathscr T(\mathrm d\mathbf x)\hat x_i |\mathbf x\rangle = (x_i + \mathrm dx_i)|\mathbf x+\mathrm d\mathbf x\rangle - x_i |\mathbf x + \mathrm d\mathbf x\rangle$$
$$= \mathrm dx_i |\mathbf x+\mathrm d\mathbf x\rangle = \mathrm dx_i |\mathbf x\rangle + \mathscr O(|\mathrm d\mathbf x|^2)$$
$$\implies [\hat x_i, \mathscr T(\mathrm d\mathbf x)] = \mathrm dx_i \ \mathbb I + \mathscr O(|\mathrm d\mathbf x|^2)$$

---

Typically we don't define the multiplication of kets by vectors, so when you see an expression like this it should be interpreted as shorthand (though we should also remember that vector operators have well-defined transformation properties under rotations).

Comment: It's making a lot of sense now. Thank you :)