# What is the identity operator of the ket space spanned by $| \mathbf{x'} \rangle$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators

In Sakurai's Modern Quantum mechanics' first chapter's section on translation, the author introduces the infinitesimal translation operator $T(d \mathbf{x})$ and tries to find the commutation relation with the operator $\mathbf{x}$ to get
$$[\mathbf{x}, T(d \mathbf{x})] | \mathbf{x'} \rangle = d \mathbf{x} | \mathbf{x'}+ d\mathbf{x} \rangle \approx d \mathbf{x} | \mathbf{x'} \rangle.$$
The approximation is valid to first order in $dx$.

Now, since this is true for arbitrary $| \mathbf{x'} \rangle$, the author argues that we can write
$$[\mathbf{x}, T(d \mathbf{x})] = d \mathbf{x}.$$

The text then says that the $d \mathbf{x}$ in the RHS "is to be understood as the number $d \mathbf{x}$ multiplied with the identity operator in the ket space spanned by $| \mathbf{x'} \rangle$".

I don't understand this, because $d \mathbf{x}$ should be a vector, not a number. So my question is what exactly is the author trying to say and how does multiplying a number $d \mathbf{x}$ with the identity operator give back the vector $d \mathbf{x}$?

Comment: The LHS of your last equation is an operator, while the RHS is a number times the identity operator (which is omitted as a matter of notation), which again is an operator. Does that help? Or do you mean that $\mathrm dx$ should be a vector because $x$ is a vector? If so, then [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/724458/multiplying-euclidean-vector-with-ket-vector) should answer the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiplying euclidean vector with ket vector](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/724458/)

Comment: You would not be asking the question if only you first illustrated it in one space dimension and put a caret over operators to remind you of the fact. $d{\mathbf x}$ is a c-number 3-vector, while your second expression is an operator equation, so, for clarity, on the r.h.side, you'd have an identity acting on kets, not changing them, and a c-number $d{\mathbf x}$ multiplying each. This equation, then, has 3 components, each corresponding to the x,y,z component of  $d{\mathbf x}$, multiplying arbitrary kets without otherwise changing them. It did not help that you misquoted the text.